# A criterion for whether an ideal is contained in a principal ideal

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be a ring and $I$ an ideal. I am interested under which conditions the following holds:

> **Claim.** Suppose that any two elements in $I$ have a non-trivial $\operatorname{gcd}$. Then $I$ is contained in some non-trivial principal ideal.

For simplicity you may assume that $R$ is a UFD so that $\operatorname{gcd}$s exist and are well-defined (a GCD domain probably suffices for this too but I have no experience with them). Although this question looks quite simple, I only know of one non-trivial example where this holds. Namely $R=\mathbb Z_p[[T]]$ and by extension $R=\mathcal O[[T]]$ for $\mathcal O$ the ring of integers of some local field extension.

I asked this question some while ago on Math.SE ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4317163/a-criterion-for-whether-an-ideal-is-contained-in-a-principal-ideal)) but have received no comment/answer. There you can also find a proof of the above claim for $R=\mathbb Z_p[[T]]$. As far as I can tell, this proof does not generalize notably.

> Are there some reasonable conditions one can put on $R$ to make the above claim work? By reasonable I mean something not making the assertion trivial (e.g. not taking a PID but maybe UFD+Noetherian suffices).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your *definition* of "has a non-trivial gcd" being contained in a principal ideal?  It is clear to me that that implies having a non-trivial common divisor, but it's not clear to me that there would be a greatest such—I guess in the divisibility ordering.

Comment: @LSpice I changed the wording. I'm only interested in containment anyways.

Comment: If your ring is a Noetherian domain, then there will always be a minimal principal ideal $fR$ such that $I \subseteq fR$. Proof: Let $\mathcal{J}$ be the set of ideals $J$ such that there is an $f \in R$ with $J = f^{-1} I$. Then there must be a maximal $J$ in $\mathcal{J}$ by Noetherianity, which corresponds to a minimal ideal $fR$ with $I \subseteq fR$.

Comment: So the question is whether knowing that $g$ and $h$ have a common divisor for every $g$, $h \in I$ implies that all elements of $I$ simultaneously have a common divisor.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Yes, the question is about the existence of a common divisor for all elements of $I$ simultaneously. I'm not sure about your argument in the Noetherian case: this does allow units as $f$, doesn't it? otherwise it would't work for, say, $I=(x,y)\subset\mathbb C[x,y]$. Then the point is to ensure that $f$ is not a unit in this argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true in UFDs. Let $f$ be any element of $I$ and let $\pi_1,\dots, \pi_n$ be its irreducible factors (choosing one from each class of irreducible factors that differ by a unit). If, for some $i$, $I \subseteq (\pi_i)$ then we are done. Otherwise, for each $i$ let $g_i$ be an element of $I$ that is nonzero mod $\pi_i$.

Then $$ h= \sum_{i=1}^n  g_i \prod_{ 1\leq j \leq n, j \neq i} \pi_j$$ is an element of $I$. Because $R$ is a UFD, $\pi_i$ is a prime ideal, so $R / \pi_i$ is an integral domain. For $j\neq i$, since $\pi_j$ is irreducible and not a unit times $\pi_i$, $\pi_j$ is not a multiple of $\pi_i$, so $\pi_j$ is not a zero-divisor mod $\pi_i$. Thus

$$ h  \equiv g_i  \prod_{ 1\leq j \leq n, j \neq i} \pi_j \not\equiv 0 \mod \pi_i$$

Since $h$ is not a multiple of $\pi_i$ for any irreducible factor $\pi_i$ of $f$, $f$ and $h$ do not have a gcd, contradicting the assumption.

Comment: Well, it seems like the question was simple after all. Thank you for your help! Is there some genereal motivation for such a construction or does it just happen to work?

Comment: @mrtaurho Well, keeping track of all the irreducible elements that might divide two elements of $I$ seemed difficult, so i thought about fixing one of the elements of $I$ and letting the other vary. This gives the condition that there are finitely many prime elements such that each element of $I$ is contained in one. This seems hard to achieve for Chinese-Remainder-Theorem-y reasons, even though that theorem doesn't directly apply. But this construction is a version of the construction used in the proof of the CRT, just missing the (here, unnecessary) invertible factors.

Comment: @Will: You can streamline the proof by using prime avoidance: Let $\pi_1,...,\pi_n$ be the prime factors of a fixed $0\neq f_0 \in I$. If $f$ is any element in $I$, since $f,f_0$ have a gcd, one of the $\pi_i$ is a factor of $f$. Hence $I$ is contained in the union of the $(\pi_i)$ and by prime avoidance, $I$ is contained in one of them.

Comment: @tj_ This is a very satisfying argument!